# Git - Pull code from the beginning, commit after commit

Tags: git, pull

I have forked a project on GitHub, and, in order to understand how it works (to later contribute to it), I'd like to go back in time to the very first commit that was made, and then pull them one after the other, simply browsing the repo at each step, as well as seeing the diff with the previous commit.

So basically, I need to know how to do three things:

- Go back to the initial state of the repo
- Pull one commit (I don't need to edit the code, just view it)
- See the diff between this commit and the previous one

I'm assuming that I could do something like `git diff HEAD~1` for the latter. However, I have no idea how to do the two other ones, especially the very first one.

Comment: Can't you just pull the latest commit, then use a Git GUI programme like GitHub Desktop or SouceTree to easily see every single different commit that was made prior to the latest commit? Each commit would show all of the changes in that respective commit, relative to the previous commit.

Comment: Well, yes, but that would be pretty difficult to browse the entire repo at a given time. I would only see the changes, but not the whole context (as far as I know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any Git GUI -- gitk, [GitUp](http://gitup.co/), [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/), [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/), etc. -- should allow you to do what you want. Select the mainline branch and scroll back to the beginning. Then, selecting each commit, in turn, will show the diff of that commit vs the previous one.

Good luck!

Comment: On Linux, I personally favor `qgit`, press `t` shows the *file tree* and you can go back in time and inspect it for every commit quite easily.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to diff `git diff` can be used to see differences between any commits `git diff sha1 sha2`. If you want to get the local repo to a particular commit all you have to do is `get reset <sha> --hard` and the top commit will be the sha that you specify. When you're done you can pull from remote again to get your local copy in sync with the remote master

Answer (score 2):

The word "pull" has a special meaning in Git, unrelated to what you want to do.  (And, not really anything to do with your question, but I recommend not using `git pull` at all.  Use `git fetch` followed by a second Git command, which is all that `git pull` does for you anyway.  The thing is that the *right* second command may depend on what you got with `git fetch`, so `git pull` runs the *wrong* one sometimes.)

Once you have access to a repository—such as the original; there's no need to fork it, not that this really hurts either—you should `git clone` it to your local machine, using any suitable Git client.  This gives you a complete copy of everything, locally.  Now you can browse through it all at will, using `git checkout` to extract any given commit, and `git log` to view commits (or `gitk` or some GUI to view, and sometimes also `git checkout`, those commits).

Comment: Well, I forked it instead of cloning, since I'd like to contribute and make pull requests later. The problem with using checkout and git log is that there are hundreds of commits to go through, so having to scroll through the entire log is a bit tedious, which is why I was wondering if there was a way to just move forward one commit.

Comment: Yes, you'll probably want the fork later for those purposes. It's hard to move *forward* one commit in Git though: it's much easier to move *backward* (from later commits, to earlier ones). If you want to find the very first commit, simply go straight to the last shown. To do this with `git log` in a Linux shell, use some of the other Linux tools: `git log --oneline | tail`, for instance. (There are many more tools but this can get you started.)

Answer (score 1):

The answers from [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42989095/461597) and [Jamie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42989126/461597) are more apt to your question. However, if you really wanted to you could easily generate diff's/patches for each commit.

You can generate patches for every commit if you really wanted to.

```
git format-patch $(git rev-list --max-parents=0 HEAD)..HEAD
```

This will create one "patch" file from the second commit to the last commit. You can then inspect each commit individually.